# Convert $data to string

Tags: knockout.js

In my viewmodel, I have this observableArray:

```
self.sorttype = ko.observableArray(['Score', 'Count', 'Average'])
```

And my view contains this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: sorttype">
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="sort: { arr: Items, prop: $data }, text: $data"></a></li>
</ul>
```

However, this binding `data-bind="sort: { arr: Items, prop: $data }` won't accept `$data` because my custom binding `sort` is expecting the string value (e.g. 'Score', 'Count', 'Average'). Can I fix this within the view or do I need to amend my custom binding?

Comment: I think you may have a different issue here... for each iteration of the loop, $data is set to 'Score', 'Count' and 'Average' (all of which are strings)

Comment: Yep - good point. The issue was my Items object was outside of the scope of the foreach. Easily solved with `$parent.Items`